# Mediator Pattern for trivial messages?

Tags: design-patterns, mediator

Is it a good programming practice to use the mediator pattern for trivial messages (show an image viewer window etc.)  ?

```
Mediator.NotifyColleagues(Messages.DISPLAY_IMAGE, image);
```

instead of just using

```
frmImageViewer.Show(image);
```

I use the mediator program in my program a lot and was wondering how much is too much.

Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

You should use it when you don't want to create coupling between the component that shows the image  `frImageViewer` and the component that triggers the notification.

If you don't plan to ever add a new window, or your application is simple enough as not to care, you may drop the mediator.

When your application have more screens, and you need to support new ones ( for instance, a preference dialog, and an advanced prefereces dialog ) and you  don't want them to know about your controller, a mediator looks appropiate